# Why read and write can not work normally

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I write a simple server to transfer a file to the client. Here are the source codes.

```
//server.c
#include "general.h"
#define LISTENQ 10
#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define FILENAME "List"

void sendlist(int sockfd) {
    int fd = open(FILENAME, O_RDONLY);
    char readbuf[BUFSIZE];
    ssize_t n;

    if(fd == -1)
            exit(1);

    for(;;) {
            if((n = read(fd, readbuf, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
                    write(sockfd, readbuf, BUFSIZE);
            else
                    break;
    }

    close(fd);
    close(sockfd);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int listenfd, connfd;
    pid_t childpid;
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr_in *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    listen(listenfd,LISTENQ);

    for(;;) {
            len = sizeof(cliaddr);
            connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr_in *)&cliaddr, &len);
            if((childpid = fork()) == 0) {
                    close(listenfd);
                    sendlist(connfd);
                    exit(0);
            }
            close(connfd);
    }
}



//client.c
#include "general.h"

#define MAXLINE 1024
#define FILENAME "List2"

void getlist(int sockfd) {
    int fd = creat(FILENAME, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    char buf[MAXLINE];
    ssize_t n;

    if(fd == -1)
            exit(2);

    for(;;) {
            if((n = read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0)
                    write(fd, buf, MAXLINE);
            else
                    break;
    }

    close(fd);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    if(argc != 2)
            exit(1);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr);

    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr_in *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    getlist(sockfd);

    exit(0);
}
```

My problem is: the file List and List2 are not the same.
For example, the content of file List is:`test`
Content of file List2 contains not only `test`, but also many unreadable codes like this:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<8c>]úUü^?^@^@ ^G^\Vü^?^@^@^A^@^@^
```

I think the reason are read and write function. Shouldn't I use them?
Thanks

Comment: Learn about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and search for the `C10K problem`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing the entire buffer to file, while only the first `n` bytes are valid. Replace:

```
for(;;) {
        if((n = read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0)
                write(fd, buf, MAXLINE);
```

With:

```
for(;;) {
        if((n = read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0)
               write(fd, buf, n);
```

And all similar occurrences accordingly.

Comment: We answered at the same second.

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe you need to memset the buffers first
2. send only what you actually read not everything you have
3. write only what you received not the buffer size

like

```
 for(;;) {
     memset(readbuf , 0, BUFSIZE);   // Clear Memory here
     if((n = read(fd, readbuf, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
                write(sockfd, readbuf, n); // Send what you read
        else
                break;
}



 // similarly While reading
 for(;;) {

        memset(buf , 0 , MAXLINE); // again do a memset 

        if((n = read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0)
                write(fd, buf, n); // Write What you read
        else
                break;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the memset. You just need to remember what you should send and what you should not send. Sending a lot of zero bytes is just as bad as sending random garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Read() and write() can do *partial* reads/writes. This is indicated by their **return value** which is the number of bytes succesfully transmitted, which *can* be different from the 3rd argument that was given to them.

```
while(1) {
    int n;
    unsigned todo, done;
    n = read(fd, readbuf, BUFSIZE);
    if (n <= 0) break;

    for(todo=n,done=0; done < todo; done += n ) {
        n = write(sockfd, readbuf+done, todo - done);
        if (n <= 0) return FAILURE;
        }
    }
```